# .net API post returns an object but want to override object and return a HTTP error code with description

Tags: c#, .net, api

I am receiving a post which if successfully locating data will fill and return an object named "ClientLoginOut"

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ClientLoginOut Post(ClientLogin clientlogin)
```

This works fine.

But if there is a problem looking up the data, I would like to return a Server response : 400
with a message in json formatted message.

This is what I would like to return

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Login Invalid"
}
```

I tried a return using the following

```
HttpResponseMessage message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Login Invalid");
return message;
```

But the compiler is giving this error on the "return message;" line

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
```

> Error  CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to 'Models.ClientLoginOut' APIApp  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\APIApp\Controllers\ClientLoginController.cs  165 Active

How can I override the "ClientLoginOut" object and return a custom error code with custom message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.

```
//This is the post receiving a json format and parsing to Object DebtAdd
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] DebtAdd debtadd)
```

Here is where I can return an object as a json using HttpResponse
OR a json error message

```
//This is returning an object as a json with 200 code
string jsonStringOUT = 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(debtallout);
var token = JToken.Parse(jsonStringOUT);
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, token);

//This is returning and error message with a 400 code
var messageError = string.Format("Error");
HttpError errError = new HttpError(messageError);
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errError);
```

Comment: Did you actually unaccept my answer and then accept your own?

Answer (score 0):

Just set your controller method return type to `IAsyncResponse` and return the appropriate response - in pseudo-C#:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Post([FromBody] ClientLogin clientlogin)
 {
        if (good) 
        {
            return Json(myResponseObject);
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(myErrorObject);
        }
 }
```

(don't forget `FromBody` this always burns me)

Comment: I tried your solution but received this message

CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.HttpResponseMessage' to 'Models.CLientLoginOut'

I have ClientLoginOut object as what is being returned
public ClientLoginOut Post(ClientLogin clientlogin)

You have HttpResponseMessage being returned
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] ClientLogin clientlogin)

I am hoping to override the object ClientLoginOut object with a json error Bad 400.
Is there a way to override the return of ClientLoginOut object with a HttpResponseMessage?

Comment: To get what you want you cannot have your method return type be `ClientLoginOut`. It's gonna have to be `HttpResponseMessage` or `IAsyncResult` as the other (bizareely) deleted answer correctly showed. But either way you can't just return the `ClientLoginOut` if you want to customize the response.

Comment: Bummer. Your solution does work, just not mixing it with returning an object. I opted to return the object but included a property that would store an error message. It still returns a 200 OK code so not quite the same effect but it works.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, but I'm sure we can get you what you want. If you want to return an object, you would do the same thing but return 200 in the HttpResponseMessage constructor and JSON serialize your resposne object in the StringContent. Or you could return `IActionResult` instead and use the helper methods. I'll revise the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: I figured out how to do this.